# Positive scalar curvature metric on $S^4$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, curvature

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature) article on scalar curvature says that

> If $X$ is a compact Kähler manifold of complex dimension 2
>   which is not rational or ruled, then $X$ (as a smooth 4-manifold) has no
>   Riemannian metric with positive scalar curvature.

**Question:** Let $M$ be homeomorphic to $S^4$. Give $M$ some differentiable structure. Does $M$ always admit a metric of positive scalar curvature?

I am not familiar with complex geometry, so I don't know if $M$ satisfies the above conditions.

If we assume $M$ has the standard differentiable structure of $S^4$, then the standard metric of $S^4$ has positive scalar curvature. However, I would like to know if the answer to my question is true for purely topological reasons, i.e. without assuming a differentiable structure on $M$ a priori.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an open problem as to whether or not $S^4$ admits a non-standard smooth structure (such a smooth structure is called an *exotic* smooth structure). This problem is known as the four-dimensional smooth Poincaré conjecture.

No matter which smooth structure $S^4$ is endowed with, it cannot be given a Kähler complex structure as a compact Kähler manifold $M$ has $b_2(M) = \dim H^2(M) > 0$. In fact, no smooth $S^4$ (standard or exotic) can even admit an almost complex structure.

I don't know the answer to your actual question, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is open.

Comment: For the OP:  just to add an indication that the actual question is likely open, it is known that there is an exotic $9$-sphere which admits no metric of positive scalar curvature.  So, in particular, positive scalar curvature does not happen "for purely topological reasons".

Comment: Almost complex structure of S^4 is settled now??

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee: The open problem you are probably thinking of is whether or not $S^6$ admits a complex structure.

Comment: Oh sorry ...yes you are right. Thanks :)

Comment: To build upon @JasonDeVito's comment, there are in fact such examples in dimensions $9 + 8k$ and $10 + 8k$ for every $k \geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry by mistake I down voted you ( while trying to upvote)